# Fivetran Google Cloud PostgreSQL Connector: wal_buffers Warning Issue

Tags: fivetran, gcp-cloudsql

[image]

> Issues found with configuration values
> The following parameters are not inline with best practices: wal_buffers set to 4MB. We recommend setting it to -1 for auto-adjusting in most cases, but we recommend a range of 2048 (16MB) to 16384 (128MB) for very high traffic servers, based on the 8KB unit. Please refer to our documentation for setting WAL configuration values: https://fivetran.com/docs/databases/postgresql/gcs-setup-guide#logicalreplicationwiththepgoutputplugin

How should I address the `wal_buffers` warning displayed when selecting the Google Cloud PostgreSQL connector in Fivetran?

I've tried setting `wal_buffers` to -1 in CloudSQL settings and restarted the DB instance, but the warning message remains unchanged.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?